# The central term of Binomial distribution

Tags: probability, binomial-distribution

This is from Feller's Introduction to Probability Theory and Its Applications:
we have the equation:
$$b(k;n,p)/b(k−1;n,p) =(n−k+1)*p/kq=1+ ((n+1)p−k)/kq)$$
and b(k;n,p) is greater than the preceding one for $k<(n+1)*p$ and is smaller for $k>(n+1)*p$
and from that we have got the inequality:
$$(n+1)*p - 1<m<=(n+1)*p$$
where $m$ is "the most probable number of successes.
I have understood the idea, but i can't figure out how we got the last equation?Can you explain me this step by step?

And also one more question: I have completely lost in definiton of upper and lower bound of "probability at least r successes". Can you explain me this also, or should i create separate question?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression you received for the ratio in the first expression is of the form 1+something. As long as this something is positive you get an increasing probability and once "something" becomes negative the probability starts decreasing as $k$ increases. Hence the most probable number of results is the maximal $k$ for which "something" is still positive.

Comment: Thank you, but i understood the idea:)
I mean how we have got the last equation mathematically.

Comment: Note that "something" has the form $(n+1)p-k$ divided by a positive quantity, so its sign is determined by the sign of $(n+1)p-k$. We now take $m$ to be the highest integer value of $k$ for which this sign is not negative.